# What are the differences between VMID and ASID in the context of virtualization and operating systems?

Tags: memory, arm, virtual-machine, mmu

I'm trying to understand the differences between VMID (Virtual Machine Identifier) and ASID (Address Space Identifier) in the context of virtualization and operating systems.

Refer the ([ARM Documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101811/0103/Address-spaces/Virtual-Machine-Identifiers---Tagging-translations-with-the-owning-VM)) ; *"EL0/EL1 translations can also be tagged with a Virtual Machine Identifier (VMID). VMIDs allow translations from different VMs to coexist in the cache. This is similar to the way in which ASIDs work for translations from different applications. In practice, this means that some translations will be tagged with both a VMID and an ASID, and that both must match for the TLB entry to be used.*"

While both seem to be used for identification purposes, I'm unclear on their specific roles and how they relate to each other. Could someone please provide a detailed explanation of the differences between VMID and ASID, including their purposes, usage scenarios, and scopes? Should I use ACID to tag different VMs instead of VMID? Additionally, any insights into how they impact system performance and security would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ASID is for processes and libraries.  I would call it 'application space identifier'.  You can set it per process on a context switch and different ASID will apply in the table walk.  In this way the page tables do not have to manipulated and flushed between context switches.  The VMID seems self explanatory.  It is for a higher layer (different EL state) to assign memory to another VM.  For instance, a hypervisor controlling several different VMs.

Comment: Possibly helpful?  [Domain means what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613000/domain-in-arm-architecture-means-what).  So the ASID is a register that needs to be set on a context switch.  As oppose to re-writing the entire 'translation table', flushing the TLB (MMU cache) and the CPU caches (if VIPT).  ASID is a huge optimization for context switches in an **OS**.  Each 'virtual machine' is usually a different OS.  So the VMID is like a meta-ASID.  It is said in the arm explanation (*similar to the way ASIDs work*).  VMID save time in VM switch from the hypervisor.

Comment: I think ASID (2015) is the system register formally known as DACR (2010) and superseded by 'PROCID' (2020) which was originally PID (2005).  These are all the same thing (at a high level) which are different incarnations of ARM trying to improve context switch times with virtual memory (MMU).  It will be replace by 'FSCK_C00LAID' (2025:).  Each does have different features and capabilities, which is why they were given a different name.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations @artlessnoise . I think you should write them as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: You may self answer with the aspects that  you found useful.